# Equivalent to fs.createReadStream to use with input type file

Tags: javascript, browserify

I'm using Browserify to convert a node js project (Google Drive Api uploads) in a browser frontend JS function, all works fine until I reach the line:

```
body: fs.createReadStream('./some_file.ext')
```

Where the console says that fs.createReadStream is not a function. I was trying to use an input type file to let the users choose his file before uploading but when I try to replace fs.createReadStream('./some_file.ext') with "multipartRequestBody" as shown here: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert

Then I get "Invalid multipart request with 0 mime parts".

If I try with an Undefined body, it upload it with correct metadata but its empty.

Please help :(

[EDIT] When I saw the object "fs.createReadStream" in console.log the output is:

```
ReadStream {
 _readableState:
  ReadableState {
    objectMode: false,
    highWaterMark: 65536,
    buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
    length: 0,
    pipes: null,
    pipesCount: 0,
    flowing: null,
    ended: false,
    endEmitted: false,
    reading: false,
    sync: true,
    needReadable: false,
    emittedReadable: false,
    readableListening: false,
    resumeScheduled: false,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    ranOut: false,
    awaitDrain: 0,
    readingMore: false,
    decoder: null,
    encoding: null },
 readable: true,
 domain: null,
 _events: { end: [Function] },
 _eventsCount: 1,
 _maxListeners: undefined,
 path: './some_file.ext',
 fd: null,
 flags: 'r',
 mode: 438,
 start: undefined,
 end: undefined,
 autoClose: true,
 pos: undefined,
 bytesRead: 0 }
```

I tried with FileReader() and "this.files" (from input type file) but the output in console is different. Is there any other way to get the same kind of object but with input type file?

Comment: The browser can't use the fs module. Because a webpage can't access the file system; otherwise the web wouldn't work, because JavaScript could do who knows what. So you are going to need to find a way to include an uploader

Comment: take a look at `fileReader`, here's an example : http://jsfiddle.net/vDdFy/

Comment: Thank you Taki, I used fileReader but it seems that the object is not the same as fs.createReadStream and I got the same error

Comment: I've been looking for something similar.  Fairly recently, it looks like they added a `stream()` method to [the Blob API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/stream) (which File implements).  That `ReadableStream` should be API-compatible with the Node one.

Comment: The stream() method on the blob API is scarcely supported annoyingly